# How to modify variable class from HashSet or HashMap of Class

Tags: java, class, hashmap, hashset

I have a HashSet and a HashMap of Class. How to modify the class variable?
so I have a class Data, then I create HashSet of Data and HashMap of Data
then do population. later, I would like to modify the value name and number.

```
class Data {
private String name;
private int number;

public Data(String name, int number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}

public String toString() {
    return name + ":" + number;
}
public void modifyNumber (int i) {
    this.number+=i;
} }

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Set<Data> dataSet = new LinkedHashSet<Data>();
 Map<String, Data> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Data>();
 // I do the dataSet and map population, then do something else
 //now I want to modify the value of name and number  for HashSet and HashMap of Class
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

create the `getter` and `setter` method for `Data` class
then get the object and change it

```
public void setName(String name){
this.name=name;
}

map.get("id").setName("newname");
map.get("id").modifyNumber(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

To work inside a `HashSet`, the `Data` class should override `equals` and `hashcode` methods.

Otherwise the set will not operate as expected.

In your implementation you failed to override those methods.

But when you do that, you cannot change the attribute values which are used in `equals` and `hashcode`. This may cause the object to be in the wrong hash bucket for its new value.

You can change the other attributes.

```
hashset.iterator.next().setXXX();
```